# Uploading multiple files error;

Tags: php

I have this code below(I'm working on file uploads).
at localhost it's working properly but when i upload it to my server it returns this error;

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/public_html/bookingsuccess.php on line 91**

**line 91** which is the first line of code below:

```
$allowed = ['jpg','png','gif','eps','pdf','doc','docx','xls','xlsx','ppt','pptx','ai','zip','rar'];
$succeeded = [];
$failed = [];
if (!empty($_FILES['file'])) {
    include('config.php');

    foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $key => $name) {

        if($_FILES['file']['error'][$key] === 0){
            $temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $ext = explode('.', $name);
            $ext = strtolower(end($ext));

            $file = md5_file($temp) . time() .'.'.$ext;

            if (in_array($ext,$allowed) === true && move_uploaded_file($temp, "uploads/{$file}") === true) {
                    print_r($succeeded [] = array('name' => $name, 'file' => $file));
                    $dir = "uploads/{$file}";
                    $qry = $handler->prepare('INSERT INTO store (location, name) VALUES (?,?)'); 
                    $qry->execute(array($dir, $name));
                # code...
            }else{
                $failed[] = array($name);
                echo "Some files failed to upload due to invalid file extensions";
            }

        }else{

            echo "Error";
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any response!

Comment: what's your PHP version?

Comment: The short array syntax was introduced in PHP 5.4 (see http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) so for your version you need to define your arrays using the function http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php

Comment: there's a setting on my web server where i can choose which version of PHP will my account will use. If I choose 5.4 or higher will it resolve this error??

Comment: I just used the array() function.. thanks @mishu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably are using PHP < 5.4.

According to http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php:

> As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with [].

This is shown in the example on the manual page with:

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
);

// as of PHP 5.4
$array = [
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
];
?>
```